# What does the java compiler do for refrences to a class whithin the definition of that class?

Tags: java, class

This may be a very primitive question but is something that I never paid attention. In class definition below when the compiler sees the class variable `left` to be of type `BinaryNode` what does it do as is has not read the entire definition of the class `BinaryNode` yet (BinaryNode has not been defined when the compiler is dealing with variable left)?

I mean why infinite recursion does not happen here.

```
public class BinaryNode {
    public int key;
    public BinaryNode left;
    public BinaryNode right;

    public BinaryNode(int key){
        this.key = key;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what you're asking? "What does it do" in relation to what? If you're asking just how it keeps track, the compiler will generally have a value that means "the class I'm working on right now" and will use that as a placeholder for those fields.

Comment: @chrylis I meant why infinite recursion does not happen here.

Comment: Compilers (for any object-oriented language) have to have a special-case "this class" value for their type table. Even without fields of the same type, they have to distinguish "this class" for purposes such as direct field access.

Comment: What infinite recursion means ? Can you please clarify it more ?

Comment: `left` and `right` are just reference variables. They hold references, not entire `BinaryNode` objects.

Answer (score 1):

It is no problem if a *data structure* is infinite, e.g. you can do:

```
ArrayList<Object> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(list);
```

without problems. And so it is no problem to create a class description referring to itself within the compiler. The class description may incomplete at this time and completed later just as list above could be filled with more elements after adding itself.

The important point is that there are no *operations* with the compiler trying to traverse the entire reference graph. And within the compiler there is no need for such a traversal.

So if you compile a class A referring to class B which uses class C there is not necessarily a need to touch class C. The same applies if B==C or even B==A.

Answer (score 0):

There is no infinite recursion, because `left` can hold a `null` value, so at any time a chain `aBinaryNodeObject.left.left.left./*...*/left` is finite.

Comment: but BinaryNode  has not been defined yet!

Comment: @Cgraphics and why is it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler treats it as an object of the current class that it is working with. This object has not yet been initialized and hence it holds a null value (resolves to null at this point). When it does get initialized and further action is taken on it, it searches the current class to see how to initialize it (using the corresponding matching constructor) and then allows you to work on this object and provides access to member methods and variables.
Note that static methods for these objects are directly available even without initializing (just as you would use it externally).

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge `left` is a reference variable, which has not yet allocated in memory and not pointing to anything.And as per the current declaration its not an object until  and unless we create and assign the object to this.